# C++ How to Refer to a Class' Members' Members Without Accessing Original Member

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, alias, type-erasure

Hi I know the title is a little hard to understand, and that's just because I have no idea how to phrase this problem. Fortunately, I can provide an easy-to-understand example of my problem. Imagine a base `class A` derived `class B` and unrelated `class C` setup as follows:

```
class A
{
public:
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    C c;
};

class C
{
public:
   void foo();
};
```

I want to know how to call `foo()` using an object of `class B` without doing this:

```
B b;
b.c.foo();
```

but rather this:

```
B b;
b.foo();
```

Additionally, I don't want to inherit from `class C` or make copies of `class C's` functions. Is this possible with a simple implementation? Thanks!

Comment: You example does not compile. prog.cpp:4:2: error: expected ‘;’ after class definition
 }
  ^
  ;
prog.cpp:9:5: error: ‘C’ does not name a type
     C c;
     ^
prog.cpp:10:2: error: expected ‘;’ after class definition
 }
  ^
  ;
prog.cpp:16:2: error: expected ‘;’ after class definition
 }
  ^
  ;

Comment: The short answer, there is no simple way to do it.  Regarding "and unrelated class C",  that's not true. C participates in a *composition* relationship with B. Further, class A is *completely* unrelated to the inquisition in your easy-to-understand example, so it isn't clear why it is even there. Your example could have left it out entirely.

Comment: @273K oh my bad I forgot the semicolons after class closing braces. This is an example, not the actual code.

Comment: Didn't help. prog.cpp:9:5: error: ‘C’ does not name a type C c;

Comment: The best you can do without inheritance is to implement ```void B::foo()``` as ```{ this->c.foo(); }```, which isn't exactly a copy of class ```C```'s functions.

Comment: `b.c.foo();` works. Stick with what works, unless you have a good reason not to. What is your reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints mean your example does not make sense unless the function `foo` is static; if it is not then you need to provide information about the instance of `C` you are using before `foo` makes sense; so mentioning `c` would be essential. If it is static then `C::foo` works but not `b.foo()`. If you want a member function for `B` that calls `b.c.foo()` then you should write one as suggested above.

Perhaps you meant to privately inherit C in B:

```
class B : private C , public A
{
public:
using C::foo;
};
```

will do the trick.